# Ability to update x number of rows with 1 value then increment that value

Tags: sql, t-sql

In short:
I need to massage data to what I need.

I want to be able to update a column in tableA with a value for X number of rows. After X has been reached I want the value to increment and then update X number of rows again. This should be pretty basic. What I have is below.

```
DECLARE @New_TripKey INT = 379; --where tripkey = the value to start at

IF @@ROWCOUNT < 24 --update for 24 rows
BEGIN
    UPDATE [GoogleTransit].[dbo].[Stop_Times_TEst] --update table

            --sets tripkey value = 379 and increments 379 by 1
    SET @New_TripKey = tripkey = @new_tripkey + 1 

    WHERE TripKey = 3 --this finds all current value = 3 in Stop_Times_Test


    PRINT 'Updated Rows';
END
```

I am looking for suggestions on how to move forward with this, I have looked at multiple options. Such as Merging, Cursors etc. I feel like it should be more basic than that.

~Thanks

EDIT:

```
USE GoogleTransit
GO

BEGIN --24 rows updated
DECLARE @New_TripKey INT = 379;
DECLARE @COUNTERINT INT

SET @COUNTERINT = 1

WHILE (@COUNTERINT < 22)
BEGIN --while
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TripKey ORDER BY TripKey) AS RN
          FROM Stop_Times_Loop
          WHERE TripKey = 3  
          )

UPDATE cte 
SET tripkey = @New_TripKey                --(RN-(RN-1)%24)/24 + @New_TripKey
WHERE RN <= 24
END --while
SET @COUNTERINT = @COUNTERINT+1;
SET @New_TripKey = @New_TripKey +1;
END --24 rows updated
```

NOTE: The above code updates 24 rows at a time but the WHILE condition is not met, meaning the loop continues to try and process even though all TripKey's = 3 have been updated. Also the code above does not increment the TRIP KEY number so even though it is updating 24 rows at a time the value is not changing. 
-My issue is not being able to identify where or how to increment the tripkey value after each iteration of the update of 24 rows.

If I need to clear anything up let me know.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: First 24 as ordered by what? Then what should the next batch be updated to? Also the code you show uses the quirky update approach and does not update to a constant value. Might be easier to show us a cut down example of before and desired after.

Comment: What's missing from my answer?  It doesn't need to be in a while loop because it's set to update all records from the cte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a CTE, combined with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function I think you'd get what you want easily:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RN
              FROM TableName
              WHERE TripKey = 3  
             )
UPDATE cte 
SET tripkey = tripkey + RN + 378
WHERE RN <= 24
```

Note it's updating an arbitrary 24 rows due to the `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)`, if you want to update specific rows change the `ORDER BY` clause.  If you were trying to update multiple sets you could add a `PARTITION BY` clause to the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Update:  Based on comment, you'll also want to add modulus division into the mix:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RN
              FROM TableName
              WHERE TripKey = 3  
             )
UPDATE cte 
SET tripkey = (RN-(RN-1)%24)/24 + 379
```

Comment: Thank you Goat for your response. This query updates 24 rows, but increments the value for each of those 24 rows. What I would like to do is update those 24 rows with 1 specific value, then after it reaches the end of those 24 rows, go and update another 24 rows with the same value + 1.

Comment: @KyleRD Ah, I see. You'll need modulus division as well then, see updated.

Comment: This Update with the added modulus division solved my issue, thank you for your time.